# Why might I not be able to connect SMB to my DS1817+

Tags: networking, nas, samba, smb, synology

Tried to connect with 2 different devices windows 7 and windows 10 with no luck and diagnostics didn't help. Also in the info center I hit test and it says LAN accessible even tho my devices say otherwise.

Here are my DSM settings:
Control Panel>File Services>[x]Enable SMB service

-Advanced Settings> Max=SMB3 Min=SMB2

Control Panel>Info Center>Service>SMB [x]Enable [x]Allow through firewall [ ]Port forwarding "LAN accessible"

Comment: If you drop the min to SMB1, does it work? Don't leave it like that, but just to test.

Comment: Nop still wont connect